# SQL Azure export stuck at pending

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I logged in to the Azure Portal and tried to export an SQL Azure database.
It failed numerous times before I identified an issue with the password I was using.
Then I used the correct password and got a message that there's already a request for export that is at a **pending** status.

Since it isn't running (1:30 hours already when usually it should take around 15 minutes), I would like to cancel this operation and run an export again - that will hopefully finish successfully.

How can I cancel a pending export?

Comment: Is it still pending? I have the same problem. It seems there's nothing you can do but wait.

Comment: If you are in the west-US today, check http://www.windowsazurestatus.com/Rss/SAWU

Answer (score 3):

Stop-AzSqlDatabaseActivity with resourcegroup, database, server, and operation id.

you can get operation id from the portal -> sql server->import export operations.

or with the cmdlet get-azsqldatabaseactivity.

Answer (score 1):

As i see there is no option from the management portal to stop a pending Database Export operation.

If you want to stop it forcibly, you can probably **delete the storage account/ Container** where it is getting exported and set Allow Azure Services to No under Manage Allowed IP Addresses page.

If there is further issues, you need to contact Azure support to Stop the Export operation.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to cancel the export of my Azure SQL Database. I managed to do this by upscaling my database. This way it forced the failure of the export.

Answer (score 0):

Have you "delete locks" on storage account?
Had the same issue, contacted MS and been told to remove locks on storage account. That did solve the problem.